# Regex is not matching

Tags: c#, regex

How can I write a RegEx expression to match the number begin with 090 or 091 or 0123 or 0168 or 0199 or 0124 and the length between 10 to 11 digits?

I try this but not true

```
@"^(090|091|0123|0168|0199|0124)\d{7,8}$"
```

Comment: What was your attempt? What tripped you up?

Comment: Woah, I have seen much worse questions that have not been closed, first time I will vote to reopen.

Comment: Your regex looks good, can you post the code how you call it and how the data looks like you are testing?

Answer (score 7):

The regex itself looks mostly OK, although of course it will allow 12-digit numbers, too (a four-digit start, followed by 8 further digits). To change that, I propose this:

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, 
    @"^                       # Start of string
    (?=.{10,11}$)             # Assert 10-11 character length
    0                         # Start with matching a 0
    (?:90|91|123|168|199|124) # then one of the alternatives
    [0-9]*                    # then fill the rest with digits.
    $                         # End of string", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

If you want to *find* numbers like that in a longer string, not *validate* a string, then use

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, 
    @"\b                      # Start of number
    (?=[0-9]{10,11}\b)        # Assert 10-11 character length
    0                         # Match 0
    (?:90|91|123|168|199|124) # then one of the alternatives
    [0-9]*                    # then fill the rest with digits
    \b                        # End of number", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Value;
```

(assuming that the numbers are surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters).